# 2017 Winterbash

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

Over the past few years, Stack Exchange has entertained us during the month of December with the Winter Bash. In reality this has been going on for quite some years now; I believe since 2012.

However, there has been no mention of this on meta. So the question comes automatically: Will there be any Winter bash going on this year?

Comment: ok sorry, didn't find that page before. SInce there was no marketing campaign as in previous years, I thought it wasn't going to happen.

Comment: There has never been a marketing campain before launch. Still, it's a fair question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes there will be a winterbash, [there's already a countdown to it](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/)

There's more information [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303371/winter-bash-2017-when-will-it-start-this-year) where there was a competition to guess the start date.